# GoReplay - Upload to S3 does not work

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to capture all incoming traffic on a specific port using GoReplay and to upload it directly to S3 servers.

I am running a simple file server on port 8000 and a gor instance using the (simple) command

```
gor --input-raw :8000 --output-file s3://<MyBucket>/%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.log
```

I does create a temporal file at `/tmp/` but other than that, id does not upload any thing to S3.

Additional information :

- The OS is Ubuntu 14.04
- AWS cli is installed.
- The AWS credentials are deffined within the environent

Answer (score 0):

It seems the information you are providing or scenario you explained is not complete however to upload a file from your EC2 machine to S3 is simple as written command below.

> aws s3 cp yourSourceFile s3://your bucket

To see your file you can see your file by using below command

> aws s3 ls s3://your bucket

However, s3 is object storage and you can't use it to upload those files which are continually editing or adding or updating.